# gtimelog can't find pygtk installed via Homebrew on Mac OS

Tags: python, pygtk, homebrew

I have installed Python via Homebrew.  I also installed pygtk via Homebrew

I went to install gtimelog via pip but it tells me it's already installed, it appears to have come down with Python in Homebrew

When I attempt to run `gtimelog` I get `ImportError: No module named pygtk`

It appears to be a `$PYTHONPATH` issue but I can't seem to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same issue. Read the Homebrew log:

```
==> Installing pygtk
==> Downloading http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pygtk/2.24.0
==> make install 
==> Caveats
For non-Homebrew Python, you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
==> Summary
```

The problem is that even with the right PYTHONPATH I'm getting an error when running gtimelog:

```
$ gtimelog 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gtimelog", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gtimelog==0.8.0dev', 'gui_scripts', 'gtimelog')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gtimelog-0.8.0dev-py2.7.egg/gtimelog/main.py", line 2208, in main
    tray_icon = icon_class(main_window)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gtimelog-0.8.0dev-py2.7.egg/gtimelog/main.py", line 1148, in __init__
    'style-updated', self.on_style_set) # Gtk+ 3
TypeError: <gtk.Window object at 0x10b443cd0 (GtkWindow at 0x7fe09aacd1d0)>: unknown signal name: style-updated
```

**Update:

For Mountain Lion you need to install XQuarks as apple doesn't ship X11 with their OS anymore..

As per why gtimelog wasn't opening, It is a gtimelog bug and if you edit ~/.gtimelog/gtimelogrc and set show_tray_icon to False you will get it working!